# What's the optimal bound of this graph coloring problem?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a graph with nodes $v_1, ..., v_n$ and a set of edges $E$. We denote $\chi(G)$ the chromatic number of G (smallest number of colors to color the graph such that an edge never connects two nodes with the same color) and $ω(G)$ the clique number (number of vertices of a maximal clique).

Let $x_1, ..., x_n$ be real numbers and we denote $\Delta = \max_{i, j} x_i - x_j$ the diameter of the $(x_i)_i$.

Let $M>0$ and we define the following constraints :
$$(v_i, v_j)\in E \Rightarrow |x_i-x_j|\geq M$$

I want to prove (or find a counter-example) that $$\Delta \geq (\chi(G) - 1)\times M$$

I already know how to prove that $\Delta \geq (ω(G) - 1)\times M$ but it's a weaker result.

As a small example, you can think about the graph with 5 vertices which form a ring : $\forall i, (v_i, v_{i+1})\in E$ which is a minimal example of a graph having $ω(G) < \chi(G)$.

Comment: kabenyuk, in your example, it's not allowed to have $x_i=i$ and $M=4$ because, for example, $x_2-x_1 = 1 < M$ is not allowed

Comment: If you meant $M=1$, we have $\Delta=4$ and $(\chi(G)-1)M = 2$ so the inequality holds.

Answer (score 1):

Your graphs are the complement graphs of interval graphs (with interval centered around $x_i$ and of size $M$). These graphs are [comparability graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph) and are known to be perfect graphs (their chromatic number equals their clique number).

Also, note that a five cycle can't be represented as a comparability graph, as each odd cycle of length greater than 3 must have chords, so it is not a counterexample in your problem.